# How do I use methods of another class? (Exported android project from Processing)

Tags: java, android, class, methods, processing

My project is an exported android project from Processing. It uses Fontastic library. It always force closes whenever I try to run it on my Android device. I was thinking that its because of the **font.setup()** on the MainActivity but I can not think of any solution. Please take a look on the following lines of code. Thank you.

This is the **MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;   

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static Wave font;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    font.setup();
}
}
```

and this is the class named **Wave.java**

```
import fontastic.FPoint;
import fontastic.Fontastic;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PFont;

public class Wave extends PApplet {
    Fontastic f;
    float charWidth = 512;
    PFont myFont;
    int version = 0;
    boolean fontBuilt = false;

    public void setup(){
        randomize();
        create();
    }

    public void randomize(){
        version++;
        if (f != null) { f.cleanup(); }
        f = new Fontastic(this, "WaveFont" + nf(version,4));
        f.setAdvanceWidth(PApplet.parseInt(charWidth));
        for (int i=0; i<Fontastic.alphabet.length; i++) {
            char c = Fontastic.alphabet[i];
            FPoint[] points = new FPoint[4];
            float rectSize = charWidth * 0.5f;
            float rnd = charWidth * 0.2f;
            points[0] = new FPoint(charWidth / 2 - rectSize / 2, charWidth / 2 - rectSize / 2);
            points[1] = new FPoint(charWidth / 2 - rectSize / 2, charWidth / 2 + rectSize / 2);
            points[2] = new FPoint(charWidth / 2 + rectSize / 2, charWidth / 2 + rectSize / 2);
            points[3] = new FPoint(charWidth / 2 + rectSize / 2, charWidth / 2 - rectSize / 2);
            points[0].setControlPoint1(points[0].x + rnd, points[0].y + random(-rnd, rnd));
            points[1].setControlPoint1(points[1].x + random(-rnd, rnd), points[1].y - rnd);
            points[2].setControlPoint1(points[2].x - rnd, points[2].y + random(-rnd, rnd));
            points[3].setControlPoint1(points[3].x - random(-rnd, rnd), points[3].y + rnd);
            points[0].setControlPoint2(points[0].x + random(-rnd, rnd), points[0].y + rnd);
            points[1].setControlPoint2(points[1].x + rnd, points[1].y + random(-rnd, rnd));
            points[2].setControlPoint2(points[2].x + random(-rnd, rnd), points[2].y - rnd);
            points[3].setControlPoint2(points[3].x - rnd, points[3].y + random(-rnd, rnd));
            f.addGlyph(c).addContour(points);
        }
    }

    public void create(){
        f.buildFont();
        f.cleanup();
        myFont = createFont(f.getTTFfilename(), 200);
        fontBuilt = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `font=new Wave();` before accessing methods from `Wave`

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an object of the class whose method you want to use. If you don't do that you will get `NullPointerException` because the variable `font` is not initialized.

Do this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    font = new Wave(); // You missed this line
    font.setup();
}
```